# What to do with slow partition of my HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

So I have the HDD with 600 GB of storage. It has 3 partitions (you know, system part, "c" part for windows and "d" part).

Lately, the "c" started working really really slow. I'm sure that it's because of the age of this HDD.

But "d" part works like a charm. Fast and smooth.

So I bought a new disk and want to use the old HDD as my second disk. But it slows all my system because of that crappy "c" partition. Even booting takes 3 minutes instead of 10 seconds...

What can I do with it? Can I "remove" that part of HDD somehow?

Comment: No. ... I'm not even sure where to begin here. Check the disks SMART stats, using a tool like Speedfan or CrystalDiskInfo, and confirm that the disk is healthy. if it is not, don't use any of it, and if it is, then format the partition currently holding C (after you have backed up any user files). Personally I find it hard to believe that only one partition on the disk is "slow" unless that partition is overfull, and heavilly fragmented, and both those problems would be solved by a formatting (after you have backed up any data you want!).

Comment: A partition cannot be "slow", its the same physical disk, if something is making it slow then it's unlikely an I/O problem.

Comment: You don't really get slow partitions... Start with SMART or sysinternals to see what else might be happening...

Comment: "Can I "remove" that part of HDD somehow?" - If you did that, then you would lose the OS, which isn't what you want.  You could delete the partition, but that will not solve your problem, but the approach cannot be without a complete disk format.